# Google Sheet/App Script - parameters don't match the method signature for Utilities.computeDigest

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, md5, google-apps-script-editor

Can anyone help me understand what the following means please?

> Exception: The parameters don't match the method signature for Utilities.computeDigest.

I'm trying to run a script that hashes filenames in my Google drive, but I keep getting the above error and I can't seem to find info about it.

The corresponding line of code is:

```
var fileHash = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, file);
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your second parameter (file) a String or a byte? [In the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computedigestalgorithm,-value) it mentions that the second parameter must be of type String or Byte[]. [Here is an example of the latest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computedigestalgorithm,-value)

Answer (score 2):

As Mateo Randwolf in a comment said:

> Is your second parameter (file) a String or a byte? In the
> documentation it mentions that the second parameter must be of type
> String or Byte[]

For my case, the solution was to convert it into string:

```
var str = '' + file;
var fileHash = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, str);
```

---

Ref:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computedigestalgorithm,-value,-charset